# How to round a value In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I want to round off the value in Excel when the value is greater than 5 after decimal.

For example:

- if num= **9.15**, result= **9.1**
- if num= **9.16**, result = **9.2**

Comment: right click on cell and click format cell -> number -> category -> number -> decimal places

Comment: I think I understand your problem now... 9.15 usually rounds to 9.2

Comment: Is it always the second place of decimals you need to round up or down, or the last place (could be 9.5, 9.15, 9.115 etc) ?

Comment: What you want contradicts the currently valid rounding rules.

Comment: Could you use a second column? `=if(right(A1,1)=5,right(A1,1)-1,A1)` then you use normal rounding on the  cell

Comment: Thanks all.. @Andreas it worked, but it will work where I have any specified nos of characters. Do we have any formula or any trick where we can round of only when the decimal value is greater than 5, which works on a general pattern of any character length?

Comment: @Tom- Yes its always the second place I want to round it off..

Comment: @AmanMalhotra What about values that are between 9.15 and 9.16?  e.g: 9.159?

Comment: @AmanMalhotra or 9.151; 9.155 (still rounding to one decimal)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld 9.1 or 9.2 ?

Comment: @Jasen That is my question.  The OP did not define a result for values between 9.15 and 9.16.  Due to the method in which Excel computes and stores numbers, there is no guarantee that a number that looks like 9.16 in the cell (or even the formula bar), will really be that number as stored for computations.

Comment: @AmanMalhotra it's unclear what results you want for values like 9.151 or -4.15 etc.

Comment: Maybe we're overthinking it - it might be enough to do something like =ROUND(A2-0.0000000001*SIGN(A2),1)

Answer (score 2):

Although your need contradicts the currently valid rounding rules it could be achieved with the following formula:

```
=TRUNC($A1*10^1+0.4*SIGN($A1))/10^1
```

The value in `A1` can be any decimal value in any length either positive or negative. It will be "rounded" to 1 decimal place. The `10^1` part in the formula leads to rounding to 1 decimal place. Use `10^2` to round to 2 decimal places and so on.

Answer (score 1):

For the second decimal place, I was going to post

```
=IF(AND(FIND(".",A2&".")=(LEN(A2)-2),RIGHT(A2)="5"),--LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),ROUND(A2,1))
```

(modified according to @Jasen's comment)

A very simple approach is

```
=ROUND(A4-10^-10*SIGN(A4),1)
```

which should be fine up to several places of decimals if you change the number of decimals to round (but will fail because of rounding errors if the numbers are too large).

This also gives good results over a wide range of numbers:-

```
=ROUND(A2-A2/10^12,1)
```

To generalise the first one a bit more you could try

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".",A2)),IF(RIGHT(A2)="5",--LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),ROUND(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)-1)),A2)
```

to round the last decimal place down if it's a 5.

Comment: try that with 15 in a2

Comment: Yes, it need to check for decimal places - will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

`=ceil(A1*10-0.5)/10`

Comment: Should be `=CEILING(A1*10-0.5,1)/10` for Excel. But yes, this would be another possibility. Will round down 9.15 ~ 9.1 but round up 9.151 ~ 9.2. My solution will always check only the second decimal place. So which is better depends on what @Aman Malhotra really wants.

Comment: my docs say excel has `ceil`, and also that `ceil` rounds up while `ceiling` rounds away from zero.

Comment: Which Excel version? My (Excel 2007 and Excel 2016) have not. With Excel 2016 you could do `=CEILING.MATH(A1*10-0.5)/10`

Comment: I think it would be this to round negative numbers correctly =CEILING(A2*10-0.5*SIGN(A2),SIGN(A2))/10